# What is required to run CiviCRM on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql

Amazon have scalable MySQL/MariaDB offerings in [Amazon RDS for MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) (and [Amazon RDS for MariaDB](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mariadb/)). CiviCRM uses MySQL functionality extensively, so it would be interesting to see if the two work well together.

- What experiences do people have of running CiviCRM on Amazon RDS?
- Were there any special considerations or steps to get it running?
- Were there any limitations to CiviCRM you ran into?

Comment: [a comment from chat.civicrm.org here](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/tqkh5fgpkfbb5xixaztbi6zxme)

Answer (score 3):

We haven't tried running CiviCRM on RDS yet but we have been shifting a Drupal installation across to AWS. A few things we've noted so far that are relevant:

- It helps if the RDS instance is in the same AZ as the web service
- The various RDS instances have differing network throughput. It's poorly documented and can catch you out
- Default settings for MySQL/MariaDB RDS from memory don't have caching enabled. You should be mindful of checking the paramater group for every RDS instance
- Read replicas can be your friend!